# Can I control how Classes called?

Tags: python, class, object

I wrote some code and was not sure how to make it work as expected,

```
class Bee():
    def __init__(self, name, identifier):
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier

bee = Bee(name='Bumble', identifier=1)
print(str(bee))
```

->> Should Print: **1 Bumble**

I thought of creating a function in Class Bee as follows:

```
def get_hive(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.identifier, self.name)
```

However, I am not sure how, when I create an object of class Bee, to assign given attributes instead of address of the memory cell.

My code currently ofc prints smth like: <**main**.Bee object at 0x000001EA24F49460> instead of the attributes.

Comment: You just need to do `print(bee.get_hive())`

Comment: Why do you think it *should* print the attributes. Your aren't printing the attributes, you are printing *the object*. `bee` is a `bee` object. Why do you expect it to be anything else? *You wrote* `bee = Bee(name='Bumble', identifier=1)`

Comment: or use a `__str__` method that's the same as your proposed `get_hive`

Comment: Also, after you implement `__repr__` and maybe `__str__`  - there is no need to use `str()`. `print(bee)` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `str(bee)` to return a string as you describe, implement a `__str__` method:

```
class Bee():
    def __init__(self, name: str, identifier: int):
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.identifier} {self.name}"


bee = Bee('Bumble', 1)
print(bee)
```

prints:

```
1 Bumble
```

Note that `print` will automatically call `str` on any parameter that's not already a `str`, so you can just say `print(bee)` instead of `print(str(bee))`.